# Ubuntu 12.04 Virtualbox Firewall?

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible for me to completely shut off a network connection, or block all traffic on my non-virtualized Ubuntu so that only my virtual Ubuntu is allowed to communicate with the internet?

I have tried to do this using `ufw` but if I block everything on the host side then the client shuts down to.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your VMs to bridging mode you can restrict the network traffic so that only traffic between your network device and VM is possible.

But the network device is still operated by the host so the host has still network traffic but can be restricted so that the kernel disallows any traffic from the hosts user space to the network device.

So in principle it is possible but the setup with `iptables` is not trivial. Also any kernel bugs in the host can still be there and affect your host.

Comment: Wwouldn’t this setup and method be much more secure because if someone created a VM, setup their OS, cloned it and then used that clone as their regular OS that connects to the internet, but at the same time periodically deletes that regular OS and simply creates another clone from the original setup - It seems like that would be the most secure of all virtualbox options.

Comment: @Chris but why do you want to shut your host system off of the network? The host system should also be able to update. But for surfing the internet a VM is a valid choice.

Comment: I'm looking at it from a matter of isolating a perpetual clean operating system where the host never connects to the internet and only VM's do. This way the base operating system (the host) always stays clean from internet traffic.